# How to bypass the Sails body parser for multi-part form uploads

Tags: express, sails.js, multipartform-data

I am facing a problem on Sails.js (0.9.16) with POST requests sent from a JAVA client.
On the client side I built a POST request (with enctype : multipart/form-data) sending a text file.

On the server side, I created a controller with a method (action) getRequest which looks like :

```
getRequest: function (req, res, next) {
        //var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

        console.log('req: ', req);
        return res.send(200);
}
```

But I have the following error on my sails.js console:

```
Error: 'Unable to parse HTTP body :: { [error: Expected CR Received 10] status: 400 }
```

So I saw on the Web that Express/Connect included with Sails.js was not appropriate to handle multipart data, has anybody already faced my problem and succeed to use an other middleware like busboy or formidable to handle these kind of request?

Thanks in advance.
Best
Loïc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to solve this problem as well.  Looks like skipper from the sails team is the way to go.  https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper

The docs appear to be decent w/ examples for sails 0.10.0 & 0.9.x.

See this thread on GitHub https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1521 for more info and background.

Hope this helps. FYI - The google group for sails is active.

Graham

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I tried Skipper but when I used it, I can't receive any POST request (even with POSTMAN) whereas without skipper I was able to receive POST requests POSTMAN. Maybe I missed something to do ? I will retry it again. Best Loic

Comment: From reading posts in the group it looks like skipper needs 0.10.0 to work properly.  To accept posts form an android app, we ended up creating a simple node app w/ formidable and ran it on a separate port.  Far from perfect, but it was quick, and didn't impact our existing sails app.

Comment: user285455, Indeed, I think that using Skipper with Sails.js v0.9.x is not the correct combination. Using Formidable I succeed to get post request and parse data correctly. Thanks. Best Loic